# SSL certificate verification failed when sending email with Gmail

Tags: laravel

I have tested the whole application and seems to be working really fine. However, when I tested the email with Gmail and yahoo, I got errors like these...(But database is updated with new entry though).

```
`Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation 
failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL 
routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed`


`Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com: The process was completed 
successfully`
```

I have already tested the email with mailtrap and it worked well.

So let's say it's already in production and all the credentials are set properly, would that mean there wouldn't be no error?

I'm thinking it may be coz I'm still in the development stage that's why I'm encountering these errors.

So my question as you can see above... **Should I just go with my guts and upload to live server?**

Comment: What port you are using??

Comment: I have used 465 for SSL and 587 for TLS in both Gmail and yahoo. I have carefully changed every information. Gone to my Gmail account and switched on Less Secure App access.

Comment: This is not due to development stage. Might be your ssl certificate causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First try to change the encryption in your smtp configuration to tls

```
'encryption' => 'tls'
```

If it does not work, then open `mail.php` in `config` folder and add the following:

```
'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks. So now do I have to use only SSL or can I still use both of them as usual?

Comment: Please first check the port number with SSL.

Comment: If it works with non-ssl then you should try with ssl but make sure your port is valid.

Comment: `Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
 530 5.7.0 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError t19sm452851eju.10 - gsmtp
 "` ....This is the error thrown.

Comment: I am still getting the same error @Rohit. I have tried both ssl and tls, also used the code you gave me above. `Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
 530 5.7.0 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError b17sm7648785wrx.15 - gsmtp
 "`